# how to access folder outside webroot in wildfly 8

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8

I want to access my image file outside of web directory. For example my applicable is in opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/Myproj and i want to access a file from /opt/pic/abc.jpg. Please hl how to do in wildfly. I am using wildfly-8.2.0. I deployed my war by exploded deploy. Pease help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes back i wrote an article on the similar query, Hope that might be helpful:

**How to store static contents outside WildFly installation and access them via Http ?**
http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2718

Regards
Jay SenSharma